# Virtual Host setting not working

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I am hosting two domains on a vps server. The domains, let say www.abc.net(or abc.net) and www.xyz.net(or xyz.net) have following config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName abc.net
    ServerAlias www.abc.net
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/abc.net
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/abc.net.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/abc.net.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xyz.net
    ServerAlias www.xyz.net
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/xyz.net
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xyz.net.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xyz.net.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

apart from these I have default apache2 *00-default-site.conf* (unchanged)and rutorrent.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/rutorrent.log vhost_combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/rutorrent_error.log
    SCGIMount /rutorrent/RPC2 127.0.0.1:5000

    <Directory "/var/www/rutorrent">
            AuthName "user1"
            AuthType Basic
            Require valid-user
            AuthUserFile /var/www/rutorrent/.htpasswd
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Assuming my ip as t.u.v.w I have following /etc/hosts file set

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       template.pcsmarthosting.co.uk   template
t.u.v.w         abc.net
t.u.v.w         xyz.net

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

I am able to access www.abc.net correctly as it goes to correct folder, however www.xyz.net goes to /var/www/ same as http://t.u.v.w

www.xyz.net doesn't work even when it is the only enabled site.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you enable Virtual Host File? You can use `a2ensite` command for this. `sudo a2ensite <xyz.conf>`. And restart apache.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and yes its enabled.

Comment: You enabled `NameVirtualHost *:80` in config file?

Comment: where do I do that??

Comment: In the same file where you put your Vhost configurations. Just place above the `<virtualHost *:80>` block and restart apache.

Comment: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/abc.net.conf:1

It doesn't mention anything about the modification in xyz.net.conf. Is the server not reading the conf file??

Comment: It reports each error only once. So its definitely reading the xyz.net.conf

Comment: Your configuration seems to be correct. What you can do is, try disabling abc.net.conf file and check whether xyz.net is working or not.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. I have mentioned it earlier too

Comment: you disabled abc.net and tried accessing www.xyz.net and it doesn't work? Then check your logs.

Comment: I just checked the log files. it seems my access logs are written to rutorrent.log whenever I try to access xyz.net This happened when only xyz.net.conf was enabled.

Comment: I think i got my mistake. the virtual hosts are read in alphabetical order. Damn me!!! Thanks for all the help

Comment: You can read more on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/details.html Link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Systems hostname might be  www.xyz.net , which means that 000-default acts as if it has "ServerName  www.xyz.net" implicitly.

You should put a dummy ServerName in the 000-default so there's no risk.

Comment: Hostname is set as localhost@localdomain. after disabling rutorrent.conf  it started working